# Enviar un 'TAB' al precionar la tecla 'Enter' DataGridViewCellEndEdit, C#

Tags: c#, datagrid, onkeypress

Estoy intentado que al momento de editar el valor de una `Celda` del `DataGridView` luego del evento `CellEndEdit` al precionar la tecla `Enter` enviar mediante código un `TAB` actualmente estoy utilizando el Evento `KeyPress` y el `EditingControlShowing` del Datagridview pero no ha funcionado.

**EditingControlShowing:**

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
       TextBox textbox = e.Control as TextBox;
       if (textbox != null)
       {
             textbox.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridView1_KeyPress);
             textbox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridView1_KeyPress);
        }
}
```

**Evento KeyPress:**

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // Si es un enter
    {
        e.Handled = true; //Interceptamos la pulsación
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}"); //Pulsamos la tecla Tabulador por código
    }
}
```

También he probado en el **Evento KeyDown:**

```
if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

> No funciona!, **¿Alguna idea de como lograrlo?**

He encontrado [esta respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9667066/8933039), pero no funciona correctamente.

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 & .NET Netframework 4

Comment: Has probado con:
   private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter) // Si es un enter
      {
         e.KeyChar = Keys.Tab;
      }
   }

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter) // Si es un enter
   {
      e.KeyChar = Keys.Tab;
   }
}
```

Comment: La reportaron como de baja calidad. Creo es que la respuesta correcta (no lo probe), por favor podrias expandirla un poco mas? explicando si la probaste o no, y que hace (se que mucho no se puede explicar, pero bue)

Comment: Ese código funciona, cuando se recibe el evento KeyPress, si la tecla pulsada es un Enter la cambia por un Tab. En mi caso lo tengo para sustituir un punto por una coma decimal, así que imagino que el sustituir el punto por el Enter y la coma por el Tab debe funcionar también.

Answer (score 0):

Me funciono con este a mi

```
introducir el código aquí
    private void GridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        SendKeys.Send("{tab}");
                        e = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("GridView1_KeyDown: {0}", ex), "Información", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).